# How to use Eclipse Birt 4.3 with mongoDB data source

Tags: mongodb, birt, mongodb-query

- How do you use Eclipse Birt 4.3 with mongoDB data source?
- How do you use UI provided in latest version?
- How do you write mongoDB query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mongodb-oda-birt-plugin/  or 
Try this http://www.birt-exchange.org/devshare/_/designing-birt-reports/1414-mongodb-oda-for-birt
The user guide available in the Downloads section and it will be very helpful from developing reports in BIRT

Answer (score 0):

> How do you use Eclipse Birt 4.3 with mongoDB data source?

When creating a Data Source choose MonogDb data source.

> How do you write mongoDB query?

As to writing query http://developer.actuate.com/be/documentation/ihub2-web/birtos/fg31/index.html#page/birt-os/connecting.1.48.html explains it. 
Also checkout http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/blog/10-birt-evangelist-blog/

I agree with you that documentation is lacking and no examples are given. I find it inconvenient that only one collection can be selected.